# Making one b-form-select dependent on value from other b-form-select

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two `b-form-select` elements in my application. What I want is, when the user selects value in the first `b-form-select` dropdown (i.e. a state value), depending on the value he/she selects, districts corresponding to the `state` selected are shown in second dropdown. When nothing is selected, it should show all values.

This is the code that I have currently, where both of them work independently.

```
                  <div>
                    <b-form-select id="state" v-model="form.state" :options="stateOptions">
                    </b-form-select>
                  </div>


                  <div>
                    <b-form-select id="district" v-model="form.district" :options="districtOptions">
                    </b-form-select>
                  </div>
```

`stateOptions` and `districtOptions` individually contain list of all states and districts as of now. But I have created a mapping like this to be used:

```
myMapping: [
{
    state: A,
    district: [D1,D2,D3]
},
{
    state: B,
    district: [D4,D5,D6]
},
{
    state: '',
    district: [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6]
}
]
```

How can I have this? 
I searched existing posts, but I couldn't find any answer that involves using `b-form-select`. They all involved `select` tag instead. Couldn't find any mention in the official documentation of `b-form-select` either.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
            state: 'A',
            district: ['D1','D2','D3']
        },
        {
            state: 'B',
            district: ['D4','D5','D6']
        }
      ],
      form: {
        state: '',
        district: ''
      }
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    stateOptions() {
      return this.items.map(item => item.state)
    },
    districtOptions() {
      return this.form.state ? this.items.find(item => item.state === this.form.state).district : []
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    resetDistrict(option) {
      if (option !== this.form.state) {
        this.form.district = ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-form-select id="state" v-model="form.state" :options="stateOptions" @change="resetDistrict()">
    </b-form-select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b-form-select id="district" v-model="form.district" :options="districtOptions">
    </b-form-select>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ form }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: can it be like, that if none of the `state` is selected, then `district` still appears (without any value selected) though. Currently, `district` only appears when `state` is selected

Comment: @JohnDoe Instead of `v-if="form.state"` add `:disabled="!form.state"`, which will show the select in a disabled state if no state is chosen.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo , apologies if I couldn't make myself clear. What I meant was, when nothing is selected, I have created a mapping such that `state: ' '`, all options of district get appeared. In my page when I open it for first time, the empty option of state should appear against which all options of districts should appear. Currently, the district options appear only when I explicitly go and select a state.